# Entity Framework Core NodaTime Sum Duration

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, nodatime

How do you write the following sql in EF Core

```
select r."Date", sum(r."DurationActual")
from public."Reports" r
group by r."Date"
```

We've got the following Model (mwe)

```
public class Report 
{
    public LocalDate Date { get; set; }
    public Duration DurationActual { get; set; }  ​
}
```

I tried the following:

```
await dbContext.Reports
    .GroupBy(r => r.Date)
    .Select(g => new
    {
      g.Key,
      SummedDurationActual = g.Sum(r => r.DurationActual),
    })
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

but this does not compile since `Sum` only works for `int`,`double`,`float`,`Nullable<int>`, etc.

I also tried to sum the total hours

```
await dbContext.Reports
    .GroupBy(r => r.Date)
    .Select(g => new
    {
      g.Key,
      SummedDurationActual = g.Sum(r => r.DurationActual.TotalHours),
    })
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
```

which compiles but cannot be translated by EF with the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: r.Date, 
ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: Report
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False

    .Sum(r => r.DurationActual.TotalHours)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', ....
```

Of course I can enumerate it earlier but this is not efficient.

To clarify it a bit furhter: We use `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` together with `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime` to establish the connection. `Duration` is a DataType from `NodaTime` to represent something similar like `TimeSpan`.
`Duration` gets mapped to a `interval` on the Database side.

We heavily use unit-tests which use an InMemoryDatabase (`UseInMemoryDatabase`) So the solution should work with both, PsQl and InMemory.

#### For those unfamiliar with the EF-Core integration of NodaTime:

You Add the `UseNodaTime()` method call to the configuration, example:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(
    options => options
                      .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                      .UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection"),
                            o => o
                                 .MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DependencyInjection))!.FullName)
                                 .UseNodaTime()
                        )
```

this adds a type-mapping for the NodaTime types

```
.AddMapping(new NpgsqlTypeMappingBuilder
                {
                    PgTypeName = "interval",
                    NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Interval,
                    ClrTypes = new[] { typeof(Period), typeof(Duration), typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(NpgsqlTimeSpan) },
                    TypeHandlerFactory = new IntervalHandlerFactory()
                }.Build()
```

I don't know every detail but I think this adds a ValueConverter.
Further information: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/nodatime.html

Comment: What's the actual type of the `DurationActual` column in the DB?  You're model needs to match up with that.  You can then have an unmapped property that converts the primitive type to `Duration` and back.

Comment: The actual type is `interval`. It is automaticly mapped by the ef with the help of `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime`

We can work with the Duration no problem in C# and everything works. My concern is about Summing them up in the db.

Comment: Have you configured any value converter on `DurationActual `?

Comment: No, I haven't directly. The `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime`  should add one. I have updated the question for further explanaiton

Comment: Would you not be happy with a raw SQL implementation? Given that NodaTime is highly specific to postgres and you're using non standard types (Duration instead of Timespan), there is no other way to optimise this without writing your own linq expression handler for this datatype, or asking the NodaTime devs to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL`'s source code [here](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/blob/dc0370717fb0d9fbb05cb2d785586fc16efc838c/src/EFCore.PG.NodaTime/Query/ExpressionTranslators/Internal/NpgsqlNodaTimeMemberTranslatorPlugin.cs#L70), you can see that it can't translate `Duration`'s members.
The method `Translate` will return `null` if the member used belongs to an object whose type is not `LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` or `Period`. In your case the member used is `TotalHours` and it belongs to an object whose type is `Duration`.

So your second example can be made to work if you change `DurationActual`'s type from `Duration` to `Period` (`TimeSpan` will also work).

Still, `Period`'s member `TotalHours` also can't be translated (see the [code here](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/blob/dc0370717fb0d9fbb05cb2d785586fc16efc838c/src/EFCore.PG.NodaTime/Query/ExpressionTranslators/Internal/NpgsqlNodaTimeMemberTranslatorPlugin.cs#L89) for the full list of the members that can be translated).

So you have to compute the value yourself with something like this :

```
 await dbContext.Reports
                .GroupBy(r => r.Date)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    g.Key,
                    SummedDurationActual = g.Sum(r => r.DurationActual.Hours + ((double)r.DurationActual.Minutes / 60) + ((double)r.DurationActual.Seconds / 3600)),
                })
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
```

If changing `DurationActual`'s type is not an option, you can open an issue with Npgsql developers to add the necessary translations. They suggest doing so in [their documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/nodatime.html#member-translation):

> Note that the plugin is far from covering all translations. If a translation you need is missing, please open an issue to request for it.

Comment: Thank you!
Your answer helped to steer in the right direction. I added a pull-request (https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/pull/1931) to add support for TotalHours. I also implemented a custom extension to solve my problem for now.

Comment: Glad to have been of help! and kudos to you creating the PR and sharing your solution.

Comment: fyi, if you ever need it, I updated the pullrequest to include (almost) all members of Duration & it got merged now -> in the next release you can use it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to update my answer when the next release is out.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @mohamed-amazirh helped me to steer in the right direction.
It is not possible to change to Period (Since it simply isn't a period, it's a duration).
I ended up writing a `IDbContextOptionsExtension` to fulfill my needs.

Full code here:

```
public class NpgsqlNodaTimeDurationOptionsExtension : IDbContextOptionsExtension
{
    private class ExtInfo : DbContextOptionsExtensionInfo
    {
        public ExtInfo(IDbContextOptionsExtension extension) : base(extension) { }

        public override long GetServiceProviderHashCode()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public override void PopulateDebugInfo(IDictionary<string, string> debugInfo)
        {
            return;
        }

        public override bool IsDatabaseProvider => false;
        public override string LogFragment => "using NodaTimeDurationExt ";
    }

    public NpgsqlNodaTimeDurationOptionsExtension()
    {
        Info = new ExtInfo(this);
    }

    public void ApplyServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        new EntityFrameworkRelationalServicesBuilder(services)
            .TryAddProviderSpecificServices(x => x.TryAddSingletonEnumerable<IMemberTranslatorPlugin, NpgsqlNodaTimeDurationMemberTranslatorPlugin>());
    }

    public void Validate(IDbContextOptions options) { }

    public DbContextOptionsExtensionInfo Info { get; set; }
}

public class NpgsqlNodaTimeDurationMemberTranslatorPlugin: IMemberTranslatorPlugin
{
    public NpgsqlNodaTimeDurationMemberTranslatorPlugin(ISqlExpressionFactory sqlExpressionFactory)
    {
        Translators = new IMemberTranslator[]
        {
            new NpgsqlNodaTimeDurationMemberTranslator(sqlExpressionFactory),
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<IMemberTranslator> Translators { get; set; }
}

public class NpgsqlNodaTimeDurationMemberTranslator : IMemberTranslator
{
    private readonly ISqlExpressionFactory sqlExpressionFactory;

    public NpgsqlNodaTimeDurationMemberTranslator(ISqlExpressionFactory sqlExpressionFactory)
    {
        this.sqlExpressionFactory = sqlExpressionFactory;
    }

    public SqlExpression Translate(SqlExpression instance, MemberInfo member, Type returnType, IDiagnosticsLogger<DbLoggerCategory.Query> logger)
    {
        var declaringType = member.DeclaringType;
        if (instance is not null
            && declaringType == typeof(Duration))
        {
            return TranslateDuration(instance, member, returnType);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private SqlExpression? TranslateDuration(SqlExpression instance, MemberInfo member, Type returnType)
    {
        return member.Name switch
        {
            nameof(Duration.TotalHours) => sqlExpressionFactory
                .Divide(sqlExpressionFactory
                        .Function("DATE_PART",
                            new[]
                            {
                                sqlExpressionFactory.Constant("EPOCH"),
                                instance,
                            },
                            true, new[] { true, true },
                            typeof(double)
                        ),
                    sqlExpressionFactory.Constant(3600)
                ),
            _ => null,
        };
    }
}
```

To use it, I had to add it the same way NodaTime did it:

```
services.AddDbContext<Cockpit2DbContext>(options =>
    {
        options
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("Cockpit2DbContext"),
                o =>
                {
                    o.UseNodaTime();
                    var coreOptionsBuilder = ((IRelationalDbContextOptionsBuilderInfrastructure) o).OptionsBuilder;
                    var ext = coreOptionsBuilder.Options.FindExtension<NpgsqlNodaTimeDurationOptionsExtension>() ?? new NpgsqlNodaTimeDurationOptionsExtension();
                    ((IDbContextOptionsBuilderInfrastructure) coreOptionsBuilder).AddOrUpdateExtension(ext);
                })
            .ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(RelationalEventId.MultipleCollectionIncludeWarning));
    }
);
```